# What is the name of the sign “ł”?

Tags: old-english

What is the name of this (in my opinian tyronian) sign? 
(in "[The Gospel according to Saint Matthew in Anglo-Saxon and Northumbrian Versions](https://archive.org/details/gospelaccordingt00camb/page/46/mode/2up)", 
Matthew 5:36)
[image]

Comment: Can you give more details, like what the source of the image is? It looks like an interlinear translation of Latin to ... is that really Old English? Also the font looks older... the strange symbol in question may be more easily understood if we knew the date of publication and the font name.

Comment: The "aut" means "or," so this is probably some sort of abbreviation for the English "or."

Comment: The tironian sign looks sort of like a **7** and means "and"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is an abbreviation mark used in Anglo-Saxon manuscripts particularly of religious texts presented with parallel linear translation called gloss:

> A triple gloss for the Latin word “dormitationem” (Ps. 131:4) in the Arundel Psalter. The three glosses are separated with ***the abbreviation mark “ł” which stands for Latin “uel” [or]***. ([THIJS PORCK](https://thijsporck.com/2022/10/01/you-are-truly-the-same-the-varied-nature-of-old-english-glossed-psalters/))

It's used in multiple glossed versions (different translations of the same word) of written texts like the Psalter for example.

> The Latin words are provided with two different English translations, which the scribe separates using ***the symbol ł, the abbreviation for Latin vel meaning ‘or’*** (a kind of Anglo-Saxon slash /, if you like). ([Medieval English](https://memc1500.wordpress.com/2019/05/28/research-in-focus-marcelle-cole/)).

For example in this picture:

[image]

you can actually see the Latin ***adferte*** ‘bring’ being translated by the scribe by ***OE berað*** ‘bear, carry’ but also ***bringað*** ‘bring’. The two versions or glosses are separated by this abbreviation of "or".

---

Note: All my sources speak of ***uel/vel***, whereas in your picture we can see ***aut***. Both words mean ***or***, but there is a difference:

> ***Aut*** (or) ***excludes the alternative***; ***vel*** (an old imperative of *volō*) and -ve ***give a choice between two alternatives***. ([Dickinson College](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/uses-conjunctions#:%7E:text=Aut%20(or)%20excludes%20the%20alternative,distinction%20is%20not%20always%20observed.))

Comment: And if anyone’s wondering why the gloss looks like it says “bepað ·ł· bpinsað” or something like that, it’s because the scribe was writing in [Insular minuscule](https://spotlight.vatlib.it/latin-paleography/feature/10-2-insular-minuscule) (the main text in Latin being written in [Insular majuscule](https://spotlight.vatlib.it/latin-paleography/feature/10-1-insular-majuscule-or-round-insular).

Comment: @psmears Thanks, corrected.

Comment: I wish English had different words for the two types of "or".

Comment: @Bobson For exclusion of alternatives, English has "either ... or", so it's not lacking.

Comment: @fev - Oh, the distinction definitely can be expressed, with "either ... or" and "and/or".  But a bare "or" can be ambiguous in a way that Latin apparently can't.