# What is the name of this sign?

Tags: old-english

What is the name of this sign?
(in "[Psalterium Davidis Latino-Saxonicum vetus](https://www.bl.uk/manuscripts/Viewer.aspx?ref=arundel_ms_60_fs001ar)",
Psalms 78:52)
[image]

Comment: If it helps anyone: the Latin *gregem*  means "herd, flock" here, so the word in question is likely an Old English translation of that.

Comment: Are you *sure* this isn't just slightly different calligraphy for the symbol you already asked about with [What is the name of the sign “ł”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/609725/what-is-the-name-of-the-sign-%c5%82)

Comment: @FumbleFingers I doubt it. The line being translated doesn't contain a Latin word for "or."

Comment: That Psalterium link led no-where helpful and two queries about the Question.

Why ask in English Language Usage about something so ancient, it hardly qualifies even as Old English?

Beside such, if the symbol really is obscure, why not Post some of the best available translations of that text, hi-lighting the doubts around that character?

Comment: I actually see the word *People*, so the cross reads as **P** to me.

Comment: @YosefBaskin I believe the second-to-last letter is a "d," not an "l." The third-to-last is (I think) OE "w," so it ends "eowde."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mark is an obelus n.

obelus n. from the [Oxford Reference](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/acref/9780227679319.001.0001/acref-9780227679319-e-2012)

> **Forms**     obelus n. Also (Latinate) obelo, (pl.) obeli, oboli. (a
> roasting spit)
>
> Definitions **1. A mark used in a manuscript to indicate additions,
> corrections, erasures, etc.**

It is the equivalent of an asterisk

**eowde** n. = flock of sheep which ties in with the Latin *gregem*

Comment: It's also called a **dagger,** and the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dagger_(mark)) provides further enlightenment.